# What is the recommended way to conduct a wedding?

Tags: nikah

What is the Prophet Sunnah or the recommended way to get married in Islam?

I also want an elaboration on the wedding (ceremony, feast, guests, etc.). I live in India and the marriage function varies among different people. I have lived in UAE and seen some of the Arabic marriage functions. 
But I was wondering how did our Prophet S.A.W teach us?

Comment: Please clarify "function"

Comment: By function I mean inviting the guests and treating them.

Comment: I don't understand your question but would just add: Nikah is done then the couple spend the night together and the following day, there is a Walimah (Feast) and everyone is invited. That's it. Elaborate if you meant something else.

Comment: Where do the couple spent the night together? At the girl's house or the groom's? Also I heard the feast is for the people who attended the nikkah. Comment on this please.